# Scio all saveAs txt file methods output a txt file with part prefix

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, spotify-scio

If I want to output a SCollection of TableRow or String to google cloud storage (GCS) I'm using saveAsTableRowJsonFile or saveAsTextFile, respectively. Both of these methods ultimately use

```
private[scio] def pathWithShards(path: String) = path.replaceAll("\\/+$", "") + "/part"
```

which enforces that file names start with "part". Is the only way to output a custom sharded file via to use saveAsCustomOutput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do it in beam code via saveAsCustomOutput

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.util.Transport
val jsonFactory: JsonFactory = Transport.getJsonFactory
val outputPath = "gs://foo/bar_" // file prefix will be bar_
@BigQueryType.toTable()
case class Clazz(foo: String, bar: String)
val collection: SCollection[Clazz] = ....
collection.map(Clazz.toTableRow).
          map(jsonFactory.toString).
          saveAsCustomOutput(name = "CustomWrite", io.TextIO.write()
            .to(outputPath)
            .withSuffix("")
            .withWritableByteChannelFactory(FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP))
```

Answer (score 0):

Scio's `SCollection#saveAs*` APIs are opinionated wrappers for common sinks that mimic behavior of other popular systems, and in this case, how Hadoop Map/Reduce prefix output files. So `SCollection#saveAsCustomOutput` is the right way to go if you want to access the lower level Beam API directly.